# Dynamic size execution depending of the jobs

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent, threadpoolexecutor

I need a service to execute jobs, this jobs can have light or heavy memory needed. I need a executor that depending of the jobs size and the size of the running jobs, allow execute more or discard new jobs.

Reviewing different implementations of java Executor I don't found a way to do it. Any recommendation for implement it?.

Thanks.

Comment: could you elaborate about ***jobs size*** and how do you define ***size of the running jobs*** ?

Comment: I know approximately the memory requirements of each jobs and I can add a value previously to execute it. The idea is read this value before execute a job and depending of the size and the jobs running, allow execute or wait.

The idea is a smart executor that allow execute in parallel more or less jobs depending of a criteria, like the memory that consume a job.